# Google Chrome extension database files completely removed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-sql

I have created a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp) that uses WebSQL to store state locally. It is an RSS extension so it is feeds, posts and folders. Some users are reporting fairly regularly to me that all of a sudden their feeds are completely wiped, and when they open the extension it is as if it is completely new. They get our welcome screen, and there are no traces of the any feeds, folders or posts anywhere. I have asked them to send copies of their local database directories, and there are no traces what so ever of the old sqlite file.

Now my question is: Is this a known issue? What can I do to debug this? I guess this question is best asked in a Chrome developer mailing list of sorts, but I have very little to go on. The only thing I can assume is that it is because we are using `WebSQL` and there are bugs in the implementation in Chrome. [There have been some issues previously that put the database in an awkward state.](http://erikrothoff.com/2015/04/fixing-a-broken-rss-feed-reader-failed-to-start-transaction-1546-disk-io-error/) Are there any internal Chrome logs that I can look at?

Comment: Logging: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging As for wiping, those users probably did something like clearing browsing data? It shouldn't clear extensions though... I've used Stylish-chrome for many years before it switched from WebSQL to IndexedDB and didn't encounter such issues.

Comment: Also, maybe WebSQL wasn't ready on browser start, and your extension considered the db is empty. Use `try { openDatabase(.....) } catch(e) { setTimeout(retry, 100) }`

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm The users I have asked have not done anything like clearing browser history or run CCleaner, so I don't think it's that...